# Downloadable font Helvetica not found

Tags: android, android-8.1-oreo, android-downloadable-fonts

I want to implement Helvetica font using Oreo's feature downloadable fonts. But the font is not present in Google provided font. How can I implement it using downloadable fonts.

Comment: I also saw that the "Helvetica" font is not provided by Google Font, so using "Downloadable Font" feature we can not get it. https://fonts.google.com/

Answer (score 0):

download helvetica font from below link and unzip file, you will get types of helvetica font

https://softlay.net/graphics-design/fonts/helvetica-free-fonts-download-for-pc.html